# Refresh sub-collection automatically in React Native when using Firestore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding records to a subcollection in firebase that I am rendering in the screen. The issue I am having is that the new record is not pulled and render in the screen once I do the firestore.add(). I understood that firestore/firebase pulls the new records automatically and re-renders the actual screen showing them, but in my case it doesn't work that way.
After doing the firestore.add() do I have to call some command to update the actual screen?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `onSnapshot` listeners, they should automatically get called when the underlying data changes. If that doesn't happen for you, edit your question to include the minimum complete code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subscribe to collection updates in order to actually see the update in the app.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen):

> you can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method.

It can be achieved using the following code:

```
state = {
  loading: true,
  users: []
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate) 
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // we have to unsubscribe when component unmounts, because we don't need to check for updates
  this.unsubscribe()
}

onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
  // we have to update the state
  const users = []
  querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = document.data()

    users.push({
      key: document.id,
      document,
      firstName,
      lastName
    })
  })

  this.setState({ 
    users,
    loading: false
 })
}
```

A more detailed example can be found [here](https://invertase.io/blog/getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-on-react-native).